# Display PHP While Loop Horizontally & Vertically Using Flexbox

Tags: php, css, while-loop, flexbox, display

Having a bit of an issue here. Could use some insight. I'm displaying user created events to visitors to my website. I'm using a while loop to display everything that hasn't not yet already passed. My goal is to display two separate events right next to each other, then another two below that and so on. Currently I'm using the flex box css property to achieve this, but it's only displaying the output vertically and not the way I want it to, meaning it's only putting one event per line. Here is my current output for displaying the events.

```
include 'db_connect.php';
        $event_type = $_POST['event_type'];
        $state = $_POST['state'];
        $current_date = date("Y-m-d");
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM events WHERE event_type LIKE '%".$event_type."%' AND state LIKE '%".$state."%' AND end_date > '$current_date' ORDER By end_date ASC";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        if (isset($_POST['search-events']) && !empty($event_type) && !empty($state)) {
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                $event_name= $row['event_name'];
                $image = $row['image'];
                $start_date = $row['start_date'];
                $end_date = $row['end_date'];
                $start_time = $row['start_time'];
                $end_time = $row['end_time'];
                $street = $row['street'];
                $city = $row['city'];
                $state = $row['state'];
                $zip_code = $row['zip_code'];
                $id = $row['event_id'];
                echo '<div class="filter-wrap">';
                    echo '<div id="filter-boxes">';
                        echo '<div id="list_image"><img src="'.$image.'"></div>';
                        echo '<div id="list_name">'.$event_name.'</div>';
                        echo '<div id="list_date">'.$start_date. ' - ' .$end_date. '</div>';
                        echo '<div id="list_time">' .$start_time. ' - ' .$end_time. '</div>';
                        echo '<div id="list_location">'.$street.''.$city.''.$state.''.$zip_code.'</div>';
                    echo '</div>';
                echo '</div>';
        }
    }
```

Then there's the css that I'm using.

```
.filter-wrap {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    padding: 10px;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

#filter-boxes {
    border: 2px solid #999;
    text-align: center;
    width: 50%;
    height: 150px;
    }
```

As you can see, I'm using the flex property inside the container that holds each of the individual boxes that holds each event. I have the flex direction set to row since I want it to display horizontally, then go the next line after it runs out of room on each line.

I tried a few things. I tried switching to the css column count property but didn't get the results I was expecting. I honestly probably didn't tweak with that property enough, but I have my heart set on the flex box property. I also tried setting the flex direction to column and also tried adding an inline-block display property to the boxes that are suppose to repeat on the while loop with each event. I'm finding this online that are kind of similar to my issue, but not quite. One uses javascript, but this can obviously also be accomplished somehow with php. I also found several articles talking about centering the content using flexbox, which is not the goal here.

Answer (score 1):

Try move your `.filter-wrap` div element to outside of the `while() {}` loop.

Your current coding:

```
while() {
  echo '<div class="filter-wrap">';
    echo '<div id="filter-boxes">';
      // content goes here...
    echo '</div>';
  echo '</div>';
}
```

will result in following structure where each `.filter-wrap` only container a single child `.filter-boxes`, which will always results in vertical presentation:

```
<div class="filter-wrap">
  <div id="filter-boxes"> content </div>
</div>
<div class="filter-wrap">
  <div id="filter-boxes"> content </div>
</div>
<div class="filter-wrap">
  <div id="filter-boxes"> content </div>
</div>
```

For horizontal presentation, the correct structure should be one `.filter-wrap` consists of multiple `.filter-boxes` childs:

```
<div class="filter-wrap">
  <div id="filter-boxes"> content </div>
  <div id="filter-boxes"> content </div>
  <div id="filter-boxes"> content </div>
</div>
```

So you can try change your coding to:

```
echo '<div class="filter-wrap">';

while() {
  echo '<div id="filter-boxes">';
    // content goes here...
  echo '</div>';
}

echo '</div>';
```

Snippet for demo to you the coding logic result. It is in JS but you just have to apply the same in your PHP

Hope it helps and Happy coding!

```js
var result_1 = document.getElementById('result_1');
var result_2 = document.getElementById('result_2');

var content_1 = '';
var content_2 = '';

content_2 = '<div class="filter-wrap">';

for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
{
  // result 1
  content_1 += '<div class="filter-wrap"> <div class="filter-boxes">content ' + i + '</div> </div>';
  
  // result 2
  content_2 += '<div class="filter-boxes">content ' + i + '</div>';
}

content_2 += '</div>';

result_1.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', content_1);
result_2.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', content_2);
```

```css
.filter-wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 10px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.filter-boxes {
  border: 2px solid #999;
  text-align: center;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50px;
  
  /* for two columns display */
  max-width: 49%;
}

#result_1,
#result_2 {
  background-color: lightgray;
  border: 1px dashed black;
  margin: 3px;
}
```

```html
result 1
<div id="result_1"></div>

result 2
<div id="result_2"></div>
```

Comment: I did what you said along with a few additional tweaks and it now works! Thanks! I feel dumb for not realizing on my own that the main wrap area should be outside of the loop, but definitely glad that someone brought that to my attention.

Comment: Don't mention it! ^_^